# Can Kazakhstan nationals transit through Turkey now that entry to their citizens has been suspended?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, turkey, covid-19, kazakhstan

My wife, from Kazakhstan, is looking for ways to get back to her home country after visiting me in the UK. She has recently been granted a visa extension until July 31 due to an inability to travel safely.

The COVID situation in KZ is worsening, and they are entering a second lockdown. Prior to this, for a very small window, the only way she could've entered KZ would've been flying from London via Istanbul. Now, Turkey has temporarily suspended entry to KZ citizens due to the new Kazakh lockdown.

In the event that the UK home office will not extend visas any further beyond July 31, my wife will be extremely hard-pressed to travel back to KZ on time. If she absolutely must leave, would it still be possible for her to transit through Turkey on her way to KZ? Or does suspended entry mean by all means, entry and transit alike?

I am highly concerned about her flying back to a country that is clearly still unsafe, but if the UK will not extend visas further, she will have no choice without overstaying.

Comment: @marc, would there be flights from Turkey if they close the border? It is rather likely that those flights will all be cancelled, due to lack of people traveling if not due to the rules.

Comment: @Willeke, very possible; and this is another reason for my concern. If it is impossible for her to leave the UK, what is she to do without them extending visas further?

Comment: Have you looked into her moving into the UK with you? Officially for long term but you can change your mind(s) if it is safe for her to return 'home'. This does depend on your status in  the UK and the actual rules, which I do not know.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not meet the criteria for a spouse visa at this time. That is why she is here on a visit visa for now.

Comment: That's up to the country, there are no general rules here. I have seen some Covid-19 bans with provisions to allow transit. I would suggest editing the question to focus on the current Turkish rules specifically.

Comment: If your wife is physically unable to return home, I'm sure she could apply for an emergency extension

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the US Embassy does have [a list of flights that are still operating](https://kz.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/) with other options including transits through Frankfurt or Amsterdam, either of which should be easily reachable from London and permit transit for Kazakh citizens.

Comment: @mlc, unless I'm reading it wrong those are flights FROM Kazakhstan to Frankfurt and Amsterdam, not the other way around. Besides that, since flights are not available to be booked through London to Kazakhstan via the layover stop, it would need to be on separate tickets - this is a problem as she would need to "enter" the country just to connect to the second flight. She needs a visa to do that.

Comment: @marc sorry, I should've been clearer. The US embassy is of course more interested in flights out of Kazakhstan than flights into it, but Air Astana at least claims to be [selling tickets in both directions](https://airastana.com/kaz/en-us/Information/Important-Notices/Coronavirus-update) for those eligible to travel on them.

Comment: @mlc yet, the issue remains that she is unable to get to Kazakhstan from London via Frankfurt/Amsterdam except, in theory, with separate tickets - at this time, this is not possible.

Comment: There is a Lufthansa flight leaving Frankfurt to Almaty on July 19, 2020 for Kazakhstan citizens. Also Air Astana is flying regular flights to Frankfurt and Amsterdam.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its now obsolete

Answer (score -6):

Are you sure that this report is correct **or** that it applies to Kazakhstan citizens coming from the United Kingdom?

I just attempted a [Visa application](https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/Visa) as

- Kazakhstan citizen
- consulate London
- single transit

and it returned **You are exempt from visa**.

---

> Air Astana has been advised by the Turkish authorities that due to the extended quarantine announced by Kazakhstan on 2 July, entry to Turkey **for Kazakhstan citizens and residents** will be temporarily suspended with immediate effect. Flights between Almaty and Nursultan, and Istanbul and Antalya, will continue to operate albeit to a modified schedule, in order to bring Kazakh citizens presently on vacation in Turkey back home at the end of their holiday. Air Astana has been advised by the Turkish authority that this is a temporary measure.

This emplies persons **presently** in Kazakhstan.

You should contact the Turkish Consulate to make sure that a Kazakhstan citizens arriving **from the UK** (and not from Kazakhstan) may enter Turkey to return home.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa application - T.C. Dışişleri Bakanlığı Konsolosluk İşlemleri](https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/Visa)

Comment: Mark, do you mean about her needing a visa for Turkey? She does not need a visa for that country, but that is not the issue.

Comment: "Air Astana has been advised by the Turkish authorities that due to the extended quarantine announced by Kazakhstan on 2 July, entry to Turkey for Kazakhstan citizens and residents will be temporarily suspended with immediate effect. Flights between Almaty and Nursultan, and Istanbul and Antalya, will continue to operate albeit to a modified schedule, in order to bring Kazakh citizens presently on vacation in Turkey back home at the end of their holiday. Air Astana has been advised by the Turkish authority that this is a temporary measure."

Comment: @marc I could find no notice about a general ban for Kazakhstan. That report emplies that they can return. So I would contact the Turkish Consulate to make sure that a Kazakhstan citizens **arriving from the UK** (and not from Kazakhstan) may enter Turkey to return home.